# Dispatch DOM event from children to parent from function not DOM element (without createEventDispatcher)

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component, svelte-store

I'm trying to understand if there is a way to forward DOM event (form's one) to parent after calling a function internally.

**REPL**: https://svelte.dev/repl/8eb540552faa4651a398b182fa5cdd48?version=3.24.1

As you can see I call `validate()` in `Form.svelte` with `<form on:submit|preventDefault={validate}>`.

After that I need to re-dispatch event / call the `handleOnSubmit()` in `App.svelte`, the parent.

Is there a way without using `createEventDispatcher`?

Comment: what is wrong with use `createEventDispatcher` ?

Answer (score 0):

How about defining the `<form>` element as an export which you can then use in its parent and define a `onsubmit` eventlistener? You can use `export let form;` and `bind:this={form}` on the `<form>`.

In Form.svelte:

```html
<script>
    export let form;
    
    function validate() {
        console.log("I'm the validate() function")
    }
</script>

<form bind:this={form} on:submit|preventDefault={validate}>
    <input>
    <button type="submit">
        Please save me
    </button>
</form>
```

In App.svelte:

```html
<script>
    import Form from "./Form.svelte"
    import {onMount} from "svelte"
    
    let form;
    
    onMount(()=> {
        form.onsubmit = handleOnSubmit
    })
    
    function handleOnSubmit() {
        console.log("I'm the handleOnSubmit() in App.svelte")
    }
</script>

<Form bind:form={form} on:submit={handleOnSubmit}>
</Form>
```